Is there a function in Excel to enter a variable number within a formula?
I want to create a spreadsheet for tracking stock levels. I will be using a barcode scanner to enter various part numbers of which I want to track the totals.
I have started with a SUM IF formula but wondered if there was a way of simplifying this as there may be quantities of up to 30 to be added for a range of different parts.
The formula I have started with to allow up to a quantity of 5 items is:
=SUM(IF(N1:N106="xxxxx",1,0),(IF(N1:N106="xxxxx *5",5,0)),(IF(N1:N106="xxxxx *4",4,0)),(IF(N1:N106="xxxxx *3",3,0)),(IF(N1:N106="xxxxx *2",2,0)))

xxxxx is a part number and I would need a similar formula for all part numbers.
*2,*3 etc allows the operator to  change the quantity rather than scan each individual item.
I hoped the variable quantity could be included in the formula without having to create a separate statement for each possible number.

You may want to change your data structure to use a separate column for the quantities of each line. Then it will be totally easy to total by the part number.
If the operator already enters "*4" next to the part number, there is no reason why they should not be able to do that in a separate column. Then use a Sumif() or Sumifs() function to total the quantity for that part number.

Edit: if you want to default an empty cell to a value of 1 in the total, you can tack on a Countifs() function like this:
=SUMIFS($C$3:$C$12,$B$3:$B$12,E3)+COUNTIFS($B$3:$B$12,E3,$C$3:$C$12,"")


